# Adding and replacing elements in C# array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to manipulate with some data in C#. My idea is to add them into array. Elements of that array will be (it will be array with 3 elements in it)

```
12, test11, comment12, comment23
15, test21, comment22, comment23
27, test31, comment32, comment33
... etc
```

Then, I will need to change ie. element 15 should be changed as

```
15, test21, comment22A, comment23
```

Can you help me how to work with this kind of arrays.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Jon Skeet and here is simple implementation

```
class Program
{
   class MyArrayType
   {
     public int MyInt { get; set; }
     public string Test { get; set; }
     public string Comment1 { get; set; }
     public string Comment2 { get; set; }
     public string Comment3 { get; set; }

   }

  static void Main()
  {

    List<MyArrayType> list = new List<MyArrayType>();
    list.Add(new MyArrayType { MyInt = 1, Test = "test1", Comment1 = "Comment1", Comment2 = "Comment3", Comment3 = "Comment3" });
    // so on

    list[15].MyInt = 15;
    list[15].Comment1 = "Comment";
    // so on
  }

}
```

Comment: i like this. can you tell me please how can i list all elements in the list?

Comment: foreach(MyArrayType t in list)

Comment: Sorry I am on my mobile so can't write full syntax

Comment: foreach(MyArrayType t in list) { int I = t.MyInt; //  SO ON}

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear what the elements of your array really hard - but it *does* look like there's a certain amount of structure to them. I'd encourage you to encapsulate that structure in a new type - so you might end up with a:

```
FooBar[] values = ...;
values[15] = new FooBar(15, "test21", "comment22A", "comment23");
```

or possibly likewise but with a `List<T>`. Multi-dimensional arrays (or arrays of arrays, come to that) are generally harder to work with than a single collection of some well-encapsulated type. Also, you should at least *consider* using a higher level abstraction than the array - see Eric Lippert's blog post ["arrays considered somewhat harmful"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx) for more details.

If your first value is meant to be an identifier of some kind, you might even want to change it to a `Dictionary<int, FooBar>` or a `KeyedCollection<int, FooBar>`.

Comment: hmmm, can you be more specific? i never worked with arrays of that kind.

Comment: @user198003: Arrays of what kind? I'm suggesting that you come up with your own type (I've used `FooBar` as a sort of placeholder name) to encapsulate all the data for a single entry. It's hard to be any more specific when you haven't been specific about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I agree completely with the advice in Jon Skeet's answer. In over seven years of professional development in C#, I can't remember having used multidimensional arrays more than once or twice. The language and the .NET framework offer much better alternatives for most of the situations in which we used multidimensional arrays in older languages.

That said, here is how you assign values to an existing array.

First, since your question doesn't specify a data type, let's assume you have declared the array as a multi-dimensional array of strings:

```
string foo[,] = new string[42, 3];
```

You would access the second "column," so to speak, of the 15th "row" like this:

```
foo[15,2] = "comment22A";
```

You can find quite a bit more information about multidimensional arrays in C# in [the C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: TRUE, +1 FOR  for sharing experience ;)